# Ctypes problem What is the difference between POINTER and pointer?

Tags: python, ctypes

I am new to python ctypes, What is the difference between `POINTER()` and `pointer()` , and what are their functions?

Comment: What do you understand from what the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.POINTER) say? Is there anything in particular that is confusing?

Comment: I would like to know the actual application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POINTER()` creates a type.  `pointer()` creates an instance.

For example, in C:

```c
typedef int* PINT;
```

Would be:

```py
import ctypes
PINT = ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_int)
```

Whereas:

```c
int value = 5;
int* p = &value;
```

Would be:

```py
import ctypes
value = ctypes.c_int(5)
p = ctypes.pointer(value)
```